# Использование ноутбука для работы и личных целей с жестким разделением доступа к информации

Tags: windows, безопасность, ноутбук

*Есть желание не иметь два ноутбука (один рабочий, другой личный), а ограничиться одним.*
При этом **хочу обеспечить, чтобы программное обеспечение, используемое для работы, не имело возможности "знать" о личных задачах.**
Два уровня:

1. не знало бы как используется установленное ПО (время работы, личные интересы, содержание почты, журналы браузеров, логин от SO и т.д.);
2. вообще не знало, какое ПО установлено и используется в другом "сегменте" (например, что установлен и используется PyCharm).

Первый уровень более приоритетен для меня, но вижу риск, что зная о ПО, доберутся и до данных.

Речь идет как *о защите от внутриорганизационного наблюдения, так и о защите от сбора информации, например, мессенджером для целей поставщика мессенджера или спецслужб* (о чем организация может и не знать).

Сейчас на целевом ноутбуке стоит Windows10 (модель хорошая, но Windows11 на него не встанет).
В принципе, есть возможность получить ноутбук, куда Windows 11 встанет, хотя не хотелось бы с этим возиться сейчас.

**Какие есть варианты в моем положении для защиты от:**
а) Случая 1;
б) Случаeв 1 и 2.

Идеально было бы просто завести двух пользователей при входе в Windows.
Если это не защитит и надо, например, разделять на уровне загрузчика - сколько лицензий мне будет нужно - одна или две?

Comment: Поставьте виртуальную машину для работы.

Comment: Двойная загрузка. Оба диска (или раздела) зашифрованы разными ключами.

Comment: @user7860670, cпасибо за ответ. Я правильно понимаю, что при виртуальной машине мне понадобится двойной комплект лицензий на ПО?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, cпасибо за ответ. Я правильно понимаю, что при двойной загрузке мне понадобится двойной комплект лицензий на ПО?

Comment: Скорее всего да. И в случае виртуалки и в случае двойной загрузки готовьтесь к двойному комплекту лицензий.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ясно, спасибо. Пожалуй, попрошу на работе мне купить ноут.